# Loop $POST variable with a counter

Tags: php

I am making a multiple choice question and on the first page radiobuttons look like this

```
$resultx = $connx->query($sqlx);
$qcounter = 1;
echo '<form action="result.php" method="post">';
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultx)) {
    echo '<tr><td>Question '.$qcounter.'<br/></td></tr>';
    //output a row here
    echo "<tr><td>".($row['Question'])."</td></tr>";
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '[]" value="A" id="question-1-answers-A"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">A)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerA']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '[]" value="B" id="question-1-answers-B"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">B)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerB']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '[]" value="C" id="question-1-answers-C"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">C)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerC']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '[]" value="D" id="question-1-answers-D"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">D)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerD']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '[]" value="E" id="question-1-answers-E"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">E)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerE']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="question-id[]" value='.($row['id']).'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="question_bar_code[]" id="question_bar_code" value='.($row['CorrectAnswer']).'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><br/></td></tr>';
    $qcounter++;
    }
echo "</table>";
echo '<div>';
echo '<input class="hvr-fade1" type="submit" value="Finish">';
echo '</div>';
echo '</form>';
```

I have a counter (qcounter) to name the radiobuttons, and the name of the radiobuttons are q1, q2, q3, q4 for each question as they are looped through depending on the number of questions.

Now my second page where I analyze the results I have this code to retrieve and see the selected radiobuttons:

```
<?php
$qcounter = 1;
$answer1 = $_POST["q".$qcounter];
foreach($answer1 as $item1) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$item1."</td></tr>";
    $qcounter2++;
echo "</table>";  
}
?>
```

But it only echos the selected radiobutton for q1

Any way I can have them all echoed?

Comment: You counter is always set to `1` in the first line inside the loop: `$qcounter = 1;` What exactly do you expect there?

Comment: As Dekel said, move $qcounter = 1; to outside of the loop and it should work.

Comment: p@Dekel I understand that, I want to change ["q".$qcounter]; to q1, q2, q3 and etc each time it passed in the loop but I don't know how to put that within the loop

Comment: @Dekel sorry about that but the $qcounter = 1 is actually on my real code outside the loop as you said and I checked the html on the browers each questions radiobuttons are q1, q2, q3 ... but `["q".$qcounter]`  on the second page remain q1

Comment: @OliverFox if the question is wrong - the answer can't be right. Update the question to be accurate.

Comment: @Dekel just did so, sorry abt that, tried to simplify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the counter outside the `loop` and use it inside the loop:

```
$qcounter = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultx)) {
    echo '<tr><td>Question '.$qcounter.'<br/></td></tr>';
    echo "<tr><td>".($row['Question'])."</td></tr>";
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '[]" value="A" id="question-1-answers-A"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">A)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerA']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '[]" value="B" id="question-1-answers-B"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">B)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerB']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '[]" value="C" id="question-1-answers-C"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">C)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerC']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q' . $qcounter . '[]" value="D" id="question-1-answers-D"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">D)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerD']).'</label></td></tr>';
    $qcounter++;
}
```

### update

After the change to the question, here is a better answer:

You should change all the `input` you have to multi-dimensional array:

```
$resultx = $connx->query($sqlx);
$qcounter = 1;
echo '<form action="result.php" method="post">';
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultx)) {
    echo '<tr><td>Question '.$qcounter.'<br/></td></tr>';
    //output a row here
    echo "<tr><td>".($row['Question'])."</td></tr>";
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q[' . $qcounter . '][]" value="A" id="question-1-answers-A"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">A)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerA']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q[' . $qcounter . '][]" value="B" id="question-1-answers-B"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">B)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerB']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q[' . $qcounter . '][]" value="C" id="question-1-answers-C"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">C)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerC']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q[' . $qcounter . '][]" value="D" id="question-1-answers-D"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">D)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerD']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="q[' . $qcounter . '][]" value="E" id="question-1-answers-E"/><label for="question-1-answers-C3">E)&nbsp;'.($row['AnswerE']).'</label></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="question-id[]" value='.($row['id']).'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="question_bar_code[]" id="question_bar_code" value='.($row['CorrectAnswer']).'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><br/></td></tr>';
    $qcounter++;
    }
echo "</table>";
echo '<div>';
echo '<input class="hvr-fade1" type="submit" value="Finish">';
echo '</div>';
echo '</form>';
```

And now - after the user `post`ed the form - you should walk-through the `$_POST['q']` array to get the relevant values:

```
foreach ($_POST['q'] as $qid => $answer1) {
    foreach($answer1 as $item1) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><td>".$item1."</td></tr>";
        $qcounter2++;
        echo "</table>"; 
    }
}
```

> You better use `var_dump($_POST['q']);` or even `var_dump($_POST['q'][1]);` to get a better overview of the data you receive from the browser after the submission of the form.

Comment: maybe add a note, that when using a counter the array `[]` is not neccessary anymore? Or that it could be done without the counter? It's burning my eyes... Also the radio won't work anymore, right?

Comment: @Jeff if he wants to get the values as Array in the server side (after submit) he does need to use the `[]`, so I'll not remove it so fast. Regarding the `radio` - why shouldn't it work now?

Comment: because radios with different names won't act as radios would normaly do (to be options) - they will act as checkboxes

Comment: @Jeff but for each loop they will all have the same name, so they do act as radio.

Comment: @Dekel thanks a bunch, it works, wasnt sure about foreach within foreach!

Comment: @OliverFox you are welcome. Next time - pay attention to your question, the information you provide and what the reader can understand from it. You could get the correct answer about 25 minutes ago if only I had the relevant/correct information in the question.

Comment: @Dekel absolutely! Thanks again!